# .net mvc design ajax calls (Where to put ajax methods)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, software-design

Hi
When migrating from ASP.NET to MVC ASP.NET it looks like the MVC is more AJAX friendly.
but still I run into design issue,
Does someone knows Microsoft intention about the design when calling AJAX methods?
Where do I need to put this methods by default, in a separate controller, the same controller?
Is there any kind of official info about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is any *official best practices*. Personally I like to follow [RESTful conventions](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting) when organizing cotrollers and actions no matter how those actions are consumed (AJAX or not).

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try on having a review on [some asp.net samples here](http://www.asp.net/mvc). This will give you some ideas. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking SessionState into consideration when making the choice of method placement.

For instance, I would move ajax actions into a separate controller if I am using session state in regular actions, but not in ajax actions (which makes sense for me) and I would like the ajax methods to execute asynchronously. Then I put those ajax methods in a separate controller and mark the controller as [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] (or ReadOnly). I have found this to be a great improvement in terms of performance.

Note, that you use Session when you use TempData, ViewData or ViewBag variables.

SessionState is explained here:
[ASP.NET MVC and Ajax, concurrent requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326817/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-concurrent-requests)