# Is it sane to use Thread.Sleep(int) in ASP.NET or should I use another method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread-sleep

I want to introduce a slight wait during some testing functions, to simulate a server call. Is it sane to use `Thread.Sleep(int)` to introduce the wait or is there a better method to have the server wait?

Note, I'll be pausing long enough for me to visually see a sufficient lag, even tho I don't expect to see such a delay in the actual app. This is for me to visualize the actual delay that *could* occur.

I plan on running this both in the VS2010 local debugger webserver and in IIS 7. I'm on .NET 3.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep(int)` is what I would use.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MVC and SessionState your requests will be automatially serialized - so if you're checking for race conditions with a random `Thread.Sleep()` value then Request B will never complete before Request A even if the time slept if less.

[ASP.NET MVC and Ajax, concurrent requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326817/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-concurrent-requests)

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly fine for your test sceanrio. As long as you are not doing stress/load testing or calls to services are synchronous replacing them with simple Sleep gives close approximation of server behavior.

If your code uses asynchronous service calls you may want to emulate slightly more of the service calls and put Sleeps on separate threads as if you call service, but it took long time. This way ASP.Net will behave normally and you may even try some load testing.

Comment: When you say "simple Sleep" do you mean "Thread.Sleep(int)" as I gave the example or do you mean something else?

Comment: @drachenstern, I sense that you are hoping that there is a `Thread.Dream(int)` in addition to `Thread.Sleep(int)`. How many different ways do you need to pause?

Comment: @Nick ~ No, I want to make sure that there's not something better for ASP.NET on account of the threadpool model where it could have impacts I'm not considering.