# ASP.Net Custom images get a half second delay

Tags: asp.net

I've been working on a C# ASP.Net application that requires images to be customized by users. The images aren't very large, and so they are being stored in a database.

To facilitate loading them onto the pages, a single ASPX page has been created that depending on how it's posted to it loads a different image from the database.

The problem I've been seeing is that if a single page makes multiple requests (usually over 4), then each request starts getting a half second delay in the response.

I've added extra logging and run it through a performance analyzer and have not been able to find the source of the half second delays.

Question is:

- What is this delay and how can I get rid of it?

-OR-

- What is a better way of doing what I am trying to do that would avoid this entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably hitting a session lock. Disable the session if possible for these concurrent requests. For more information see:

- [ASP.NET MVC and Ajax, concurrent requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326817/asp-net-mvc-and-ajax-concurrent-requests)
- [Underpinnings of the Session State implementation in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What "performance analyzer" are you referring to?  Are you profiling your app?  A profiler should tell you exactly where the time is going.

Comment: I realized I was running it in Thread time mode, not wall time. Locks wouldn't consume CPU time, so they wouldn't show up as the times I was looking for.