# IE taking several seconds longer to complete a webservice request asp .net

Tags: ajax, performance, web-services, internet-explorer

Why might IE take several seconds longer to finish a webservice request in an asp .net webapp?
[image: difference of IE and Chrome]

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that before. Is it possible that IE is authenticated but Chrome isn't, and that's causing a different server-side code path?

Comment: do you happen to have an anti-virus product running? If so what is it and can you disable it and try again? Also disable any toolbars, addons, etc you may have running in IE. Maybe try opening an In Private IE session and an Incognito session in chrome and compare them?

Comment: It's not the anti-virus or add-ons. What do you think about this comment? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2326964/1072149